# How to check whether results of two selects are equal in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's consider a simplified case:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT 1) + (SELECT 2);
```

, which results in 3.

The following statement:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT 1) = (SELECT 2);
```

result is error `[42000][102] Incorrect syntax near '='.`.

How to find whether `(SELECT 1)` equals to `(SELECT 2)`?

Comment: what if the subqueries return sets?

Comment: @RadimBača, that's a good question! The solution may be to user EXCEPT operator, as specified at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/06fde2a3-6aad-47ac-95cd-849253d7abe5/compare-two-result-sets?forum=sqlgetstarted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (SELECT 1) = (SELECT 2)
         THEN 'equal' ELSE 'not equal' END AS result;
```

This assumes that both of the subqueries return scalars, and not actual result sets.  If you need to compare result sets, this is another story.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `EXCEPT` operator to check this-

```
declare @tbl1 table (Slipdate datetime)
declare @tbl2 table (Slipdate datetime)

insert into @tbl1 (Slipdate)
select '2018-02-01'
union
select '2018-02-23'
union
select '2018-01-01'


insert into @tbl2 (Slipdate)
select '2018-02-01'
union
select '2018-02-23'
union
select '2018-01-01'


select * from @tbl1
Except
select * from @tbl2


select * from @tbl2
Except
select * from @tbl1
```

If there is no result then both select returns same output. There is `INTERSECT` operator too.

Comment: `EXCEPT` would also return an empty result set if there are rows in table 2 that didn't exist in table 1. You would have to run it both ways around (and thus query twice) to know that empty set actually means equal sets.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator is supported in SQL Server with the help of [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql). Ofcourse, other way is CASE statement, as mentioned in another answer.

syntax:

```
IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )
```

eg:

```
SELECT
  IIF((SELECT 1) = (SELECT 1),' equal','not equal')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compare the actual results set (not scalars), you can use except operation like this:

```
if exists( 
    select Id from Table1
    except
    select Id from Table2
) or exists(
    select Id from Table2
    except
    select Id from Table1
)
begin
    -- sets are different
end else 
begin
    -- sets are equal
end
```

I know the question was (likely) about scalars, but since I was looking for comparing the results sets and this SO thread comes as the first Google result, I'm posting the answer here in attempt to help someone like me.